# Quick Exploratory Analysis of Categorical Data

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data, data-mining, exploratory-data-analysis

Does anyone know of a tool (preferably free) that does quick analysis of exploratory data mainly categorical with date. Using R and Python I can create time series and histograms, perform tests such as z and t. However a quick drag and drop tool would take away the coding aspect. I like Tableau and MiniTab but they are expensive.

Thanks!

Comment: What is "categorical with date"?

Comment: A set of data that contains values such as visits to doctors based on gender (male, female), age, and date (YYYY-MM-dd).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing to do is make facetted barcharts, which is easy enough to do in R, with ggplot2, or with the ggpairs function in the GGally package (for multivariate categorical data). The plot below shows survey responses to liking different subjects by different types of students. You can see that there are roughly two groups, one set tends to like GEO, BIO, CHEM, and the other set ALG, GEOM, STAT, with slightly less association between STAT/ALG.
[image]

Also look at the ggfluctuation2 function in GGally for examining the joint distribution between multiple categorical variables. Mosaic plots in vcd, or productplots packages. And hammock plots [image] (fairly flat lines for first three vars, and second three vars, with lots of cross-over between vars 3-4 indicates the two groups), parallel sets plots, common angle plots, and common angle plots in the package ggparallel. Also look at the extracat package in R and associated paper here [JSS Pilhofer&Unwin](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v53/i07/paper) for various types of plots for categorical data.

Comment: Please clarify the following about the facetted barcharts: **(1)** What do *1,2,3,4,5* in the x-axis mean? **(2)** What do *0,25,50,75,100* in the y-axis for BIO mean? **(3)** When x=BIO and y=BIO, what does that barchart illustrate? **(4)** when x=BIO and y=GEO, what does that barchart illustrate? Thanks! (If you could simply provide a link to a paper that explains these things, that'll be fine too. I did google image search the facetted barcharts image, but couldn't find anything.)

Comment: For the facetted barcharts, I didn't understand how you concluded *one set tends to like GEO, BIO, CHEM, and the other set ALG, GEOM, STAT* . E.g., in the STAT group, of those who scored 1 on STAT, very few scored 1 on ALG and CALC, whereas much larger numbers scored 1 on BIO, GEO and CHEM. This, to me, implies a higher correlation for STAT with BIO, GEO and CHEM, than with ALG and CALC.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. (1) 1,2,3,4.. are the categories of the variables. The authors decided it was easier to label this way than actual labels to avoid having to handle different length strings. (2) 0, 25, ... on the vertical axis are the percentage of observations, a full bar is 100% of observations, (3) this is the bar chart for the variable BIO alone (4) bar chart of BIO facetted by levels of GEO (That plot was made using the GGally package, and is documented in the paper Emerson, J. et al (2012) The Generalized Pairs Plot in JCGS.

Comment: On the next comment, the pattern of the bar heights differs between the two groups. CHEM, GEO, BIO when plotted against each other have a high on the top left, low top right and bottom left, high bottom right pattern of the bars which indicates positive association. This is not present when any of these are plotted against the other variables. This says that these three are like each other but different from the rest.